# "Point or option keyword required" error when inserting a block from Tool Palettes

Tags: autocad

I put a block in my Tool Palettes with a following command string macro

```
*^c^c_-insert block.dwg _xscale $m=$(getvar,userr2),1;  _yscale 
$m=$(getvar,userr2),1;
```

After when I insert the block I want to set both scales to 1. When I use the block from my Tool Palettes, "point or option keyword required" error comes. Yet, the blocks works how I want it to work but the error is irritating. Any ideas how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is set the scales to 1, use:

```
^c^c_-insert;block.dwg;_xscale;1;_yscale;1
```

The * at the start force the repeat of the command.

By using `$m=$(getvar,userr2),1`, you supply a point to the scale prompt, so AutoCAD thinks that you want to input a distance by selecting two points.